# How to remove a yum repo GPG key?

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, gpg

I have a custom RPM repo in Artifactory, and GPG signing keys were recently enabled.

When I ran `sudo yum check-updates` I was prompted to add the key:

```
Retrieving key from https://artifactory.example.com/myrepo/repodata/repomd.xml.key
Importing GPG key 0x12345678:
 Userid     : "John Doe <jdoe@example.com>"
 Fingerprint: 1234 5678 90ab cdef 1234 5678 90ab cdef 1234 5678
 From       : https://artifactory.example.com/myrepo/repodata/repomd.xml.key
```

I added the key, which was successful. However, I would now like to *remove* the key. I need to add the key programmatically (e.g. via Ansible) to numerous servers, and so I would like to reproduce the same behavior as before (where I am prompted to add the key) so that I can confirm that adding the key programmatically changes this behavior.

I have tried using `yum-config-manager` to unset the `gpgkey`, but the behavior remains the same (yum does not prompt me to accept the key):

```
sudo yum-config-manager --setopt=artifactory.gpgkey='' --save
```

I've additionally deleted the yum cache (`sudo yum clean all` and `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum`).

How can I remove this key from the yum repo configuration?

Version info:

```
$ yum --version
3.4.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yum has a GPG keyring for repos that support GPG metadata signing. On my system, the relevant paths for this particular repo were:

- `/var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/artifactory/gpgdir`
- `/var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/artifactory/gpgdir-ro`

I was able to delete the GPG keys from those keyrings:

```
sudo gpg --homedir /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/artifactory/gpgdir --delete-key 12345678
sudo gpg --homedir /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/artifactory/gpgdir-ro --delete-key 12345678
```

Running `sudo yum check-update` at this point still did not prompt me to accept the key. I ran `sudo yum clean metadata`, and after that `sudo yum check-update` did re-prompt me to accept the GPG key.

I found PackageCloud's page on [YUM GPG keys](https://packagecloud.io/app/prometheus-rpm/release/gpg) helpful in arriving at this solution.

Comment: With RHEL/CentOS 8 and repos managed by DNF, the keys are now stored in `/var/cache/dnf/*/pubring`.

Answer (score 10):

Using rpm you can list keys and remove them.

```
[root@apps2 ~]# rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{SUMMARY}\n'
gpg-pubkey-f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b    gpg(CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>)
gpg-pubkey-352c64e5-52ae6884    gpg(Fedora EPEL (7) <epel@fedoraproject.org>)
[root@apps2 ~]# rpm -e gpg-pubkey-352c64e5-52ae6884
[root@apps2 ~]# rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{SUMMARY}\n'
gpg-pubkey-f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b    gpg(CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>)
[root@apps2 ~]#
```

Comment: I deleted the key using rpm (`sudo rpm -e --allmatches gpg-pubkey-12345678-abcdefab`) but yum is still not prompting me to add the key.

Comment: `rpm` is not `yum`; they keep separate keyrings.